# Displaying data from database in an unordered list using a loop

Tags: php, sql, list, unordered

I always had trouble understanding how to properly generate unordered lists using loops. But now I gotta generate one and insert data from my database into it. This is how I retrieve the data from my database.

```
$sql_history = "SELECT * FROM transaction_summary WHERE transaction_Sender='$username' OR transaction_Recipient='$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql_history);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$sender = $row['transaction_Sender'];
$recipient = $row['transaction_Recipient'];
$amount = $row['transaction_Amount'];
```

How would I display the lastest 10 rows in an unordered list? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);`

The above line assigns the first record to an array named $row. You need to do this action for EVERY record that your query returned. So you should do:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $sender = $row['transaction_Sender'];
    $recipient = $row['transaction_Recipient'];
    $amount = $row['transaction_Amount'];       
}
```